# Using Pandas to get a contiguous segment of one dataframe and copy it into a new one?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using Pandas, I'm attempting to 'slice' (Sorry if that's not the correct term) segments of a dataframe out of one DF and into a new one, where every segment is stacked one on top of the other.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'TYPE': ['System','VERIFY','CMD','SECTION','SECTION','VERIFY','CMD','CMD','VERIFY','CMD','System'],
    'DATE': [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100],
    'OTHER': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110],
    'STEP': ['Power On','Start: 2','Start: 1-1','Start: 10-7','End: 10-7','Start: 3-1','Start: 10-8','End: 1-1','End: 3-1','End: 10-8','Power Off']
})
print(df)

column_headers = df.columns.values.tolist()
col_name_type = 'TYPE'
col_name_other = 'OTHER'
col_name_step = 'STEP'

segments = []
df_blank = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE': ['BLANK ROW']}, columns = column_headers)
types_to_check = ['CMD', 'VERIFY']

type_df = df[df[col_name_type].isin(types_to_check)]
for row in type_df:
    if 'CMD' in row:
        if 'START:' in row[col_name_step].value:
            idx_start = row.iloc[::-1].str.match('VERIFY').first_valid_index() #go backwards and find first VERIFY
            step_match = row[col_name_step].value[6:] #get the unique ID after Start:
            idx_end = df[df[col_name_step].str.endswith(step_match, na=False)].last_valid_index() #find last instance of matching unique id
            segments.append(df.loc[idx_start:idx_end, :])
            segments.append(df_blank)

df_segments = pd.concat(segments)

print(df)

print(df_segments)
```

Nothing gets populated in my segements array so the concat function fails.

From my research I'm confident that this can be done using either .loc or .iloc, but I can't seem to get a working implementation in.

My DF:

[image: My DF]

What I am trying to make:

[image]

Any help and/or guidance would be welcome.

Edit: To clarify, I'm trying to create a new DF that is comprised of every group of rows, where the start is the "VERIFY" that comes before a "CMD" row that also contains "Start:", and the end is the matching "CMD" row that has end.

EDIT2: I think the following is something close to what I need, but I'm unsure how to get it to reliably work:

```
segments = []
df_blank = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE': ['BLANK ROW']}, columns = column_headers)
types_to_check = ['CMD', 'VERIFY']
cmd_check = ['CMD']
verify_check = ['VERIFY']

cmd_df = df[(df[col_name_type].isin(cmd_check))]
cmd_start_df = cmd_df[(cmd_df[col_name_step].str.contains('START:'))]

for cmd_idx in cmd_start_df.index:
    step_name = df.loc[cmd_idx, col_name_step][6:]
    temp_df = df.loc[:cmd_idx,]
    idx_start = temp_df[col_name_type].isin(verify_check).last_valid_index()
    idx_end = cmd_df[cmd_df[col_name_type].str.endswith(step_name, na=False)].last_valid_index()
    segments.append(df.loc[idx_start:idx_end, :])
    segments.append(df_blank)

df_segments = pd.concat(segments)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some code to accomplish the 'slicing' I wanted:

```
for cmd_idx in cmd_start_df.index:
    step_name = df.loc[cmd_idx, col_name_step][6:]
    temp_df = df.loc[:cmd_idx,:] 

    temp_list = temp_df[col_name_type].values.tolist()
    if 'VERIFY' in temp_list:
        idx_start = temp_df[temp_df[col_name_type].str.match('VERIFY')].last_valid_index()
    else:
        idx_start = cmd_idx

    idx_end = cmd_df[cmd_df[col_name_step].str.endswith(step_name, na=False)].last_valid_index()

    slides.append(df.loc[idx_start:idx_end, :])
    slides.append(df_blank)
```

I essentially create a new DF that is a subset of the old DF up to my first START index, then I find the last_valid_index that has VERIFY, then I use that index to create a filtered DF from idx_start to idx_end and then eventually concat all those slices into one DF.

Maybe there's an easier way, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.contains`

```
segmented_df = df.loc[df['STEP'].str.contains('Start|End')]
print(segmented_df )
```

Comment: This doesn't give me the same result as I'm after. Isn't this just filtering out the rows that don't have Start or End in the step column?

Comment: yes, and  isn't that what you want?. If you have different condition requirements, please write those condition properly so that it is easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry for it not being clear, I thought it was. I'm trying to create a new df that's comprised of all segments from the verify just before each cmd row that contains start to the cmd row that contains end